# Is there a disconnected ado.net layer in UWP

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset, uwp

As title says it, is there a DataSet class available in UWP? More specifically, if I am writing a code with c# to be compiled through .Net native, is there a dataset class available similar to how it is in .Net Framework?

I couldn't find anything in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185500.aspx)

Comment: that stuff is deprecated, what do you want that for?

Comment: I want to have a disconnected layer where I can retrieve data from db and operate on it: display in gui, modify, update back to db. All what one can do with
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then create a proper strongly typed data model. Also, UWP apps are supposed to have a backend. Use a REST Web API or WCF backend. Forget dataset stuff, it's deprecated. VB6-like direct access from the UI to the database has been forgotten 15 years ago.

Comment: Are we talking about the same thing? :spy: 

I am not sure what your criteria is, ado.net disconnected layer is hardly depreciated. It is often part of a backend, can be strongly typed, etc...

Comment: `It is often part of a backend` - Only if that backend was written in 1995. Otherwise you will probably use something like Entity Framework instead. My point still stands that those things have nothing to do in a client application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at EF7. It's still on prerelease versions, but I think it does what you want.

[Getting Started on Universal Windows Platform](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/master/docs/getting-started/uwp.rst)

And here is a [sample](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/docs/getting-started/uwp/sample/EFGetStarted.UWP).

Comment: Entity is an option :yes: Though I'd rather avoid bleeding edge :D